# Why do Intel microprocessors allow Meltdown to happen?

Tags: x86, intel

In [The Meltdown Paper](https://meltdownattack.com/meltdown.pdf), the attack is described using the following assembly code:

```
 ; rcx = kernel address, rbx = probe array
 xor rax, rax
 retry:
 mov al, byte [rcx]
 shl rax, 0xc
 jz retry
 mov rbx, qword [rbx + rax]
```

The memory address `rbx + rax` would then be cached, and based on this cached address, the value `*rcx` could be deduced.

However, I do not understand why `al` would even get loaded with `*rcx` at all, if the permissions do not check out. When performing the page table walk to determine the value of `*rcx`, the lack of permissions should be apparent in the page table entry. This walk must occur prior to the value being loaded, regardless of our order of execution of instructions. Thus,

**Why was the load into `al` even allowed at all?**

Comment: http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/05/meltdown-microarchitecture/

Answer (score 3):

To achieve the highest performance possible, it's necessary for a CPU to do many things in parallel.

For example, when accessing something in memory the CPU might want to fetch the data and do permission checks in parallel (and then revert everything back to a previous state if the permission checks fail); because that's faster (for the "likely case" where the permission checks do pass) than doing the permission checks first and then doing fetching the data after the permission checks pass.

Of course if this means the fetch causes something to be brought into the CPU's cache before the permission checks are done; then that's "fine" because the cache isn't really supposed to be part of the architectural visible state anyway. In other words, if the permission checks do fail then you wouldn't need to revert the cache back to a previous state (which would be hard/expensive), because software "can't" depend on the exact contents of the cache.

This all seems perfectly reasonable, doesn't it?

However...

If software uses speculative execution to trick the CPU into fetching some data, where the address of the data being fetched depends on a value in kernel space, then that can happen before the permission checks are finished and then everything (except the cache) would be reverted back; and if the software uses timing to determine which address was fetched into cache then software can use this information to determine the value in kernel space that the address depended on.

Essentially; Intel made design decisions to improve performance that seemed perfectly reasonable at the time. It's only with the benefit of hindsight that we can see the security flaw.

Comment: Why is it faster to do permission checks and data fetching in parallel? In the case the data is in memory, aren't the permissions right there in the page table entry? Thus, permissions should be known before the page table walk ends, no? I feel like, if anything, permission checks would be faster.

Comment: @extremeaxe5: If it takes 2 to 1234 nanoseconds to fetch from somewhere (e.g. maybe CPU's store buffer with no TLB lookup involved) and 2 nanoseconds to do the permission check; then every fetch will be 2 nanoseconds faster if its done in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

From the paper:

> Meltdown exploits the out-of-order execution of modern CPUs, which
>   still executes instructions in the small time window between the
>   illegal memory access and the raising of the exception

[Out-of-order](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution) execution is used for performance optimization.